# Filtering the row that has the 2 same words

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

I want to filter the rows that have the **two same words** from the dataframe.

The dataframe that I have look like:

```
        Invitation

0     (Anna, Lia, Kim)

1     (Angela, Tom, Yoon, Tom)

2     (Lily, Mina, John, John)

3     (Ella, Kim, Annie, Caesy)

4     (Bella, Kate, Lyon)
```

the output that I want is:

```
         Invitation

0     (Anna, Lia, Kim)

1     (Ella, Kim, Annie, Caesy)

2     (Bella, Kate, Lyon)
```

I first made the dataframe into the list

```
df_name["Invitation"] = df_name["Invitation"].tolist()
```

but I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: is that `("Anna", "Lia", "Kim")` or `"(Anna, Lia, Kim)"` stored in the row?  What is the type?

Comment: I tried `df_name["Invitation"].dtype ` and the output was `dtype('O')`

Comment: can you suggest me why (Bella, Kate, Lyon) should be in the output?

Comment: for index 1, "Tom" is listed twice, and for index 2, "John" is listed twice. The rest of the rows all have the name just once!

Comment: @Lyliie - Can you test what is `print (type(df_name.loc[0, "Invitation"]))`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter rows if there are tuples by compare if same length of sets and values of tuples - so removed rows with 2 or more duplicated words:

```
print (type(df_name.loc[0, "Invitation"]))
<class 'tuple'>

df = df_name[df_name['Invitation'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) == len(x))]
print (df)
                  Invitation
0           (Anna, Lia, Kim)
3  (Ella, Kim, Annie, Caesy)
4        (Bella, Kate, Lyon)
```

If need remove rows with exactly 2 words:

```
from collections import Counter

mask = df_name['Invitation'].apply(lambda x: any(v == 2 for k, v in Counter(x).items()))
df = df_name[~mask]
print (df)
                  Invitation
0           (Anna, Lia, Kim)
3  (Ella, Kim, Annie, Caesy)
4        (Bella, Kate, Lyon)
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove rows with specific words in the list twice? For example, removing all the rows with "John" twice but not removing the rows with other names twice?

Comment: @Lyliie - Then use `df = df_name[~df_name['Invitation'].apply(lambda x: any(v == 2 and k == 'John' for k, v in Counter(x).items()))]`